# CCSprite not appearing on screen when in action/block

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c-blocks, ccsprite

Hello I am trying to make a game in cocos2d-swift, what I am trying to get is when the user taps on the screen and then two CCSprites that are on the screen stop and remove them selfs from the scene. Once they remove the same exact sprites again show up but have a random chance to become 3 other sprites (all properties same except color and type). The problem is I have everything working the code is executing in the correct areas but the sprites are not appearing on the iphone.

Here is the main code to replace the existing sprites.

```
- (void)resetPerimeterShape {

[baseShape removeFromParent];
[innerShape removeFromParent];

id resetAction = [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^(void){

      baseShape = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:baseShapeShape];
    baseShape.position = ccp(self.contentSizeInPoints.width/2,self.contentSizeInPoints.height/2);
    baseShape.color = baseShapeColor;
    baseShape.rotation = shapeZRotation;
    [baseShape setScale:baseShapeSize];
    [self addChild:baseShape];

    innerShape = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:innerShapeShape];
    innerShape.position = ccp(self.contentSize.width/2,self.contentSize.height/2);
    innerShape.color = innerShapeColor;
    innerShape.rotation = shapeZRotation;
    [innerShape setScale:baseShapeSize];
    NSLog(@"starting");
    //this is running and outputting so i am 100% sure this function is called.
    [self addChild:innerShape];
    NSLog(@"done");




}];
id reRunAction = [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^(void){
    //endsscene wip
}];



[self runAction:[CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[resetAction,reRunAction]]];

}
```

This is a snippet of the code where it is called.

```
 else{
                //[self runAction:self.sounds];
                NSString *A = [self randomShape];
                NSString *B = [self randomShape];

                if ([A isEqualToString:B]) {
                    baseShapeShape = A;
                    innerShapeShape = A;

                }
                else {
                    baseShapeShape = @"SQUARE (1).png";
                    innerShapeShape = B;

                }


                innerShapeColor = [self randomColor];
                baseShapeColor = [self randomColor];
                shapeZRotation = [self randomRotation];
                [self resetPerimeterShape];
                nap = true;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to run the action? For instance:

```
[self runAction:resetAction];
```

Comment: I ran it near the bottom of the first code I ran in a sequence array .

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution I was Scaleing the sprite by 0 so it basically didn't show up